# Android create custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have an arraylist of object from type book.
and this is my object

```
  public class Book

   {

   private String title;
    private int id;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title=title;
    }

    public int getid()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setid(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

}

I want to view the title only in the android listview,
and how can i get the id for every title during the item onClick action.
pls need help.

Comment: This my custom adapter  public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
 public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
   ArrayList<Object> listItems) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId, listItems);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

  TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        
  return view;
 }
}

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, not in comment. Just think yourself, can you make out from the above comment, if you got some error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    Book item = (Book) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int selected_id = item.getId();

    Log.i("selected id:--->", selected_id+"");

  }

});
```

Please also paste your full activity code (if you are getting any error while trying), so that we can help you with ease.

**Edit:**

Check the second answer given below for displaying just the title. Just write this method  in the `Book` class:

```
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you but how can i create custom adapter to only view the book title only in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

.The default ArrayAdapter object calls the toString() method on each object, so you could just write:

```java
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

If you want to create your own ArrayAdapter, you'd write something like this:

```java
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.your_book_layout;
    private Book[] books;

    public BookAdapter(Context context, Book[] books) {
        super(context, layout, books);
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(LAYOUT, parent, false);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)).setText(books[position].getTitle());
        return row;
    }
}
```

[This page](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) has a lot of information on ArrayAdapters including improving the performance.